# How to add images to a deck of cards in an automated way?

Tags: python, animation, texturing, 3d-view, add-on

[image]

I am adding png to material for each Plane Object, problem is I have 1000 of these plane objects for 1000 images to import for each one.

Is there an addons or script I could use for that please because it's very time consuming as you can imagine and it's killing my eyes?

Comment: Does each object receive a different image?  If not, you could just assign the same material to every object.  If so, how would you tell a script which image to use for each object?

Comment: 1000 different images indeed, I was hoping there would be a script out there which could do it matching the name of the image and the name of the object : example   Plane001.png for the material of Plane001 object

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Blender 3.0.0

Try the below python script for 1,000 Planes with PNG materials.

It should produce:
Plane000 to
Plane999
(Note: starts at zero to give you 1,000 Planes)

Also in this code the images should be located in "C:\img\Plane000.png", etc...

Make sure all PNG files are there

Maybe test with 15 at first!

```
import bpy

# -- create planes
for idx in range(0, 1000):
    # ---- Name for this plane
    plane_name = "Plane" + f'{idx:03}' # ie "Plane000"
    
    # ---- Create the Plane
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=1)
    obj = bpy.context.active_object
    obj.name = plane_name
    
    # ---- Create the Material for the plane with PNG
    mat = bpy.data.materials.new("material-" + plane_name)
    mat.use_nodes = True
    nt = mat.node_tree
    # -- Material Output node
    n_mout = nt.nodes['Material Output']
    n_mout.location = (200,0)
    # -- BSDF material
    bsdf = nt.nodes["Principled BSDF"]
    bsdf.location = (-200,0)    
    # -- Texture img
    n_texImg = nt.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')    
    filename = plane_name + ".png"
    bpy.data.images.load("C:/img/" + filename)
    n_texImg.image = bpy.data.images[filename]
    
    n_texImg.location = (-600, -100)
    # -- Links
    nt.links.new(n_texImg.outputs['Color'], bsdf.inputs['Base Color'])
    
        
    # ---- Add material to plane
    obj.data.materials.append(mat)
```